# Max Date where another column value equals FALSE only not TRUE

Tags: sql-server-2012

```
I have a table

emp_id    Visit Date     non_billable    
 1         5/2/2021       FALSE
 1         5/5/2021       FALSE
 1         5/6/2021       TRUE
```

Tried something similar to this:

```
Measure =
VAR LatestDate =
    CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'Table1'[visit_date] ), ALL ( 'Table1' ) )
RETURN
    ( ( 'Table1'[non_billable] ) = FALSE )
```

Trying to find the MAX date for visit_date where non_billable = FALSE
So for emp_id = 1 Max Date would be 5/5/2021 not 5/6/2021

Answer (score 0):

you can use the window function like below.

use `case` expression to check for `non_billable` = `FALSE`

```
max(case when non_billable = 'FALSE' then visit_date end) over (partition by empid)
```

Answer (score 0):

Answered thank you:

Measure:

Max_Date = CALCULATE(MAX(vwQLK_999_ClientVisit[visit_date]),vwQLK_999_ClientVisit[non_billable]=FALSE())